# Embedding Marketing Cloud Editor in a SPA

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, fuel

We are referencing  [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.exacttarget.meta/exacttarget/node_4509.htm)  for embedding ExactTarget in our Dummy Single Page Application (for Proof of Concept), but it seems either some cdn have changed or methodology has changed.

Does anybody know what's changed?

Comment: Those docs are outdated - I don't think you can embed the editor in that manner currently.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embedding cloud editor into our solution](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/65470/embedding-cloud-editor-into-our-solution)

Comment: Can you help with the approach or direct us to a latest link/document